# Bokeh Pandas legend outside plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh with Pandas Dataframe. However, the legend is printed over the boxplots. Therefore, I would like to place the legend outside the plot.

```
p = BoxPlot(df, values=ica, label=label, legend=False,
            title="{} Summary (grouped by {})".format(ica, label))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not straightforward to control the legend of bokeh.charts. I would create a BoxPlot using glyphs follwing this [code](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/boxplot.html) and then add a legend as explained [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area)

Comment: Here is the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4941) related to adding this level of control.  As @VinceP mentioned, while it require more lines of code, the `bokeh.plotting` api is probably the best option currently available to get this level of control.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to rearrange the x-values to make room for your legend (probably just easier to go with the lower level API).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the answer below does not make reference to the `BoxPlot` from `bokeh.charts` in the original question, because `bokeh.charts` was deprecated and removed in 2017*

---

It has been possible for some time to place legends outside the plot, see:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area

Here is a complete example that will work with Bokeh `0.13.0`:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="hover", tooltips="$name @fruits: @$name")

rs = p.vbar_stack(years, x='fruits', width=0.9, color=colors, source=data)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None

legend = Legend(items=[(fruit, [r]) for (fruit, r) in zip(fruits, rs)], location=(0, 30))
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

show(p)
```

[image]

For a BoxPlot specifically, you might have a look at [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/boxplot_chart.html) which is a high level API built on top of Bokeh.